# error using uasort with multidimensional array: undefined index

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

i have this array

```
$array["4E-952778"][0]['fileName'] = "File 1";
$array["4E-952778"][0]['product'] = "Muse On Demand";
$array["4E-952778"][1]['fileName'] = "File 2";
$array["4E-952778"][1]['product'] = "Muse On Demand";   

$array["15210"][0]['fileName'] = "File 3";
$array["15210"][0]['product'] = "4Manager"; 
$array["15210"][1]['fileName'] = "File 4";
$array["15210"][1]['product'] = "4Manager";
```

and im trying to sort it using `uasort()` this way:

`uasort($array, function ($a, $b) {
     return strcmp($a['product'], $b['product']);
   });`

but im getting an error: undefined index product

Comment: When you sort the array, you are only sorting based on the outermost dimension. Therefore the $a and $b don't have index product, they have indexes 0 and 1. And inside those would be product

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:-

```
uasort($array, function ($a, $b) {
     $i=0;
     return strcmp($a[$i]['product'], $b[$i]['product']);
});
```

Comment: Sorry, rather than edit, delete is happen. but i reposted it. Please have a look.